# read with sudo: why still permission denied

Tags: permissions

I use `sudo su` to become `root` and run a (borg) backup on a filesystem mounted at `/mnt`. Some of the directories and files have permissions `0600` and I receive `permission denied` when trying to read a file.

I had the (obviously wrong) understanding, that the user root can read all files, independent of the specific protection and that after `sudo su` the process runs as `root`.

What is the correct understanding? I have seen answers to similar questions, but do not understand the principles.

Practically: what protection must I set to make directories and files readable to a process running with under `sudo su`?

Comment: Are you packing up *to* `/mnt`, or *from* `/mnt`? Are these errors occuring for `/proc`?

Comment: Is it NFS-mounted?  NFS has extra rules to allow / deny root privileges.

Comment: I read from /mnt. borg mounts with FUSE (of which I do not know much).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but as I reconsider what I did, I found that in this case I mounted with NFS. I tried to find an answer but could not see what applies to my case.

Comment: As an aside, `sudo su` is unnecessary. It's like saying "Hello `sudo` please can I have root permissions to run the `su` command ... _yes ok_. Great. Hello `su`, I know we're already root but please make me root ... _uh ok_". Just use `sudo -s`

Comment: By default, root does not have root privileges on NFS-mounted directories. Look up the `no_root_squash` export option.